# Are projective transformation linear and why?

Tags: projective-geometry, linear-transformations

As the title, I would like to know: Are projective transformation linear and why?

I'm talking about [projective transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography), [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) in terms of homogeneous coordinates.

I can prove that in this context, all linear transformations are projective. But I cannot verify the opposite statement.

Could you guys please help me?

Comment: You are going to explain what you mean, exactly. A map from a projective space to itself cannot be linear, because the projective space is not a vector space.

Comment: Really? But projective transformations can be represented by matrices if we use homogeneous coordinates. As this link http://web1.kcn.jp/hp28ah77/us27d_infi.htm
"Projective Transformation changes a straight line into a straight line. So it is a linear transformation. It can be expressed with matries. In homogeneous coordinates it is;"

Comment: Homogenous coordinates generally translates to non-linear (affine transformations, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.  If by "projective transformation" you mean any collineation of the projective space, they can all be obtained by composing a linear map with an automorphism (this is the Fundamental Theorem of Projective Geometry), so they are not necessarily linear.  If you are specifically referring to homographies, then they are always linear.